# How do I recursively rename files with cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename

How do I recursively rename files with CMD?

Deleting goes like this: `DEL /S /Q image.jpg`

so i thought renaming would be something like this

`REN /S /Q configfile.xml config.xml`

But that is not working. All the examples I find on the internet are only about renaming the file extension.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `ren /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the information presented. You are not new to this site, and should be well aware of the steps you should take before asking a question. You should always check the usage information for every command, especially if it is your only one, instead of asking others. Your question should therefore be deleted, because it is of no future use to our visitors, who should also have read the usage information too. The rest of your question, has been answered before many times here, and available via the site search facility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy enough with PowerShell. When you are satisfied that the correct files are renamed correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Rename-Item` command.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter 'configfile.xml' |
    ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName 'config.xml' -WhatIf }
```

If you must run from a cmd.exe prompt or .bat file script:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter 'configfile.xml' |" ^
    "ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName 'config.xml' -WhatIf }"
```

Answer (score 0):

`ren` or `rename` does not have the `/s`earch parameter. but we can simply use a `for` loop to to use the `/s` function of `dir` to search the files, then rename the results:

From cmd:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b /s "configfile.xml"') do ren "%~i" config.xml
```

and in a `batch-file`:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s "configfile.xml"') do ren "%%~i" config.xml
```

You can also incorporate `findstr` if you really want.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s ^| findstr /i "configfile.xml"') do ren "%%~i" config.xml
```